# Mvvmcross Presenter in Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am working on mvvmcross framework and try to learn it. I have some difficulties when to develop Android project.

I have a main page where everything happens, and I want to put a Login Screen Model on top of that. I do not want to do them as activities because I do not want to destroy the main page to show login page. I just want to show a model on top of that

In iOs this can be done by using Presenter. How can i use the same method for android? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a Presenter for this too - just use that presenter to show a dialog or fragment (or dialogfragment) rather than an activity in this case.

The default Presenter MvvmCroos provides in Android is Activity based - but it's easy to override it so that it shows different types of things in different scenarios. Search for custom presenters in Android MvvmCross for more info (I'm on mobile typing right now - so can't easily add links)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I am using activity right now because I dont really understand how fragment works, it seems difficult for me. I also created a Presenter now it seems it works thanks again